# Return statement in recursive function with try-except structure not executed / returns NoneType

Tags: python-3.x

In order to test whether a function works for one of multiple parameters, I created a recursive function with a try-except structure.
The function arrives at the return statement after recursion with the correct output, but the return statement returns a NoneType object as if there is no return statement.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import datetime as dt

# Bombard function with different tryinputs untill it works or all options are tested.
def tryexcept(function, tryinputs, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        if True:#contains_explicit_return(function):
            output = function(tryinputs[0],*args,**kwargs)
            if type(output) == dt.date:
                print(output)
                return output
            else:
                raise ValueError("Output didn't return datetime.date object.")
        else:
            function(tryinputs[0],*args,**kwargs)
    except:
        if len(tryinputs) > 1:
            tryexcept(function,tryinputs[1:],*args,**kwargs)
        else:
            raise ValueError("WARNING: All tried inputs failed.")


# Date Conversion Functions
def stringtotime(stringformat,string):
    output = datetime.strptime(str(string),stringformat).date()
    return output


# Execution part

tryinputs = ['%d/%m/%Y %H:%M', '%d/%m/%Y %I:%M %p', '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M', '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p',
             '%d/%m/%Y  %H:%M:%S', '%d/%m/%Y  %I:%M:%S %p', '%m/%d/%Y  %H:%M:%S',
             '%m/%d/%Y  %I:%M:%S %p']
test = '29/9/2020  13:02:00'

output = tryexcept(stringtotime, tryinputs, test)
```

After which the following is printed:

```
2020-09-29
```

But the variable 'output' contains a NoneType object:

```
In [176]: type(output)
Out[176]: NoneType
```

I cant figure out why this is the case, and I can't find any post where the same problem was encountered. Does anyone have any idea why this is the case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  1 from datetime import datetime
  2 import datetime as dt
  3 
  4 # Bombard function with different tryinputs untill it works or all options are tested.
  5 def tryexcept(function, tryinputs, *args, **kwargs):
  6     try:
  7         if True:#contains_explicit_return(function):
  8             output = function(tryinputs[0],*args,**kwargs)
  9             if type(output) == dt.date:
 10                 return output
 11             else:
 12                 raise ValueError("Output didn't return datetime.date object.")
 13     except:
 14         if len(tryinputs) > 1:
 15             output=tryexcept(function,tryinputs[1:],*args,**kwargs)
 16         else:
 17             raise ValueError("WARNING: All tried inputs failed.")
 18     return output
 19 
 20 # Date Conversion Functions
 21 def stringtotime(stringformat,string):
 22     output = datetime.strptime(str(string),stringformat).date()
 23     return output
 24 
 25 
 26 # Execution part
 27 
 28 tryinputs = ['%d/%m/%Y %H:%M', '%d/%m/%Y %I:%M %p', '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M', '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p',
 29              '%d/%m/%Y  %H:%M:%S', '%d/%m/%Y  %I:%M:%S %p', '%m/%d/%Y  %H:%M:%S',
 30              '%m/%d/%Y  %I:%M:%S %p']
 31 test = '29/9/2020  13:02:00'
 32 
 33 output = tryexcept(stringtotime, tryinputs, test)
 34 print(output)
 35 print(type(output))
```

There was just a fairly minor problem with your program. You do return a value, but not to the main program; rather you return it to the scope of the previous function call. When you return from a recursive call of `tryexcept` at line 15, you weren't accepting the output returned by the successful call. Once you get back to the top-level call to try except, it runs to the end of the function where you don't return anything so the function implicitly returns `None`.

By letting line 15 set `output` and returning `output` on line 18 at the very end of `tryexcept`, your return value can get out of the function to the main program.

Comment: Ahh that makes perfect sense actually. Thanks a lot! :)